# How to do a search funtion by letters in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing a search into my web with symfony 2.8  I have a function into my repository class to find by letters that user search:

```
public function findByLetters($string){

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u.name FROM AppBundle:User u  
            WHERE u.nombre LIKE :string')
        ->setParameter('string','%'.$string.'%')
        ->getResult();
   }
```

I think that the query is correct, but this function when I call from ajax into my twig page, return alls users in my database... And not all user contains the letter inserted.

What could be the problem? Why this function return all database names?

Thanks!

Comment: query seems ok, did you var_dump($string)? just to be sure

Comment: Reason could be the empty string. Check inspect element and see if AJAX does have the proper string value or not.

Comment: Thanks! My function was receiving a empty string.. For this was showing all.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have a typo in your code, you want to check the user name, not its "number":

```
public function findByLetters($string){

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u.name FROM AppBundle:User u  
            WHERE u.name LIKE :string')
        ->setParameter('string','%'.$string.'%')
        ->getResult();
}
```

As stated by others, be sure to check if your string isn't empty before calling `findByLetters`.